# Sqlserver: Get Meta-Info about TRN file

Tags: sql-server, backup, transaction-log

Is there any way to get the timespan of the data contained in a TRN-File?

What I have:

- A backup of a transaction-log

What I need:

- The timestamp of the first and the last entry inside the log

How do I get this information?

Comment: Are the backup files taken on the same instance where you want to retore them?

Comment: For the moment, I do not want to restore them at all. I just would like to know the file-content. But I have admin-access to the database, the files were created on (but the TRN is not present there anymore). But since this is a productive system, I cannot restore the data there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. Not with the file only, at least.

Long answer: what you can do is query msdb.dbo.backupset on the source instance to extract this information. The backup start/end date of the previous T-LOG backup is approximately the beginning timestamp of the log records conteined in each .TRN file. The end of the log chain is the backup begin/end date of that .TRN file.